# SQL Server Update / Modified Date Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am using the following trigger to track the last modified date in a table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateTimeEntry
ON dbo.TimeEntry
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.TimeEntry
    SET ModDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
```

It says "AFTER UPDATE", but even when I insert a row, it sets the ModDate column to the same as the entry date. How can I stop this from happening? I only want it to change when I make a chance to a row, not when a new row is added (it should stay NULL in this case).

Thanks!

Comment: Why you dont do it directly inside your query. rather than doing this through trigger?

Comment: Is there any chance that you have a `DEFAULT` value specified, too?

Comment: Irfan: I'm not sure I follow as this is a table and I don't know how else to do an update date.

Chris: Thanks!!!! That was it.

Comment: In this code your checking ID in inserted table which will have all the IDs of newly inserted records or New values for any updated records, Deleted table will only have old values for records that was updated. You can also change your WHERE Statment something like WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM deleted)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_my_table on my_table 
FOR UPDATE AS            
BEGIN
    UPDATE my_table
    SET modified_on=getdate()
    FROM my_table INNER JOIN deleted d
    on my_table.id = d.id
END
GO
```

OR you can change definition of or existing trigger to

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateTimeEntry
ON dbo.TimeEntry
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.TimeEntry
    SET ModDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM deleted)
```

inserted table will have all the newly inserted records and new values for any updated records, deleted table will have only old values of the records that were updated.